# Python return statement indentation level

Tags: python, indentation

Following a tutorial where indentation level of second return statement (return False) is right below for loop, so outside of loop.
Shouldn't it be inside the for loop?

```
import scrabble
letters = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz"

def has_a_double(letter):
  for word in scrabble.wordlist:
    if letter + letter in word:
      return True
  return False

for letter in letters:
  if not has_a_double(letter):
    print(letter + " never appears doubled")
```

I have another snippet where same indentation level results in incorrect output:

```
#word_list = ["one", "two", "four"]
#word_list = ["three", "five", "six", "seven", "nine"]
word_list = ["one", "two", "three", "five", "four"]
#word_list = ["one", "two", "three", "five"]
def has_o_in_it(words):
  for word in words:
    if "o" not in word:
      return False
  return True

if has_o_in_it(word_list):
  print("word list has o in it")
else:
  print("word list has no o in it")
```

When I run above snippet, result is "word list has no o in it"
Why not put the return statements all under conditional checks?

Comment: Why do you think it should be inside the loop? It would end the loop on the first iteration, *always*.

Comment: In other words, by **not** placing it in the loop you only return `False` after all items in the loop have been examined. What do you think is more correct?

Comment: I'll assume that tutorial hasn't mentioned the `any()` function?

Comment: No I haven't encountered any() function yet, but I will be checking it shortly. I guess I was confused as in above words example,my sample word_list lists did not account for possible word ordering combinations. Thank you all for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's go through the logic of `has_o_in_it(words)`:

1. There's multiple words so we need to iterate them: `for word in words:`
2. for **each** word we need to check if it contains 'o': `if "o" in word:`

   1. If word contains "o" we know the list does: `return True`
   2. If word doesn't contain "o" we need to keep checking: `continue`
3. If we get through the entire list without `returning True` we can conclude the list does not contain "o": `return False`.

So the code should look like:

```
def has_o_in_it(words):
    for word in words:
        if "o" in word:
            return True
        else: 
            continue
    return False
```

There are other (more concise ways) to write this code as well (first one is best):

```
# Uses a list comprehension and the any (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) keyword.
def has_o_in_it(words):
    return any("o" in word for word in words)

# Filters the array for only word with o, converts to list and then to 
boolean (empty lists == False).
def has_o_in_it_(words):
    return bool(list(filter(lambda x: "o" in x, words)))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have another snippet where same indentation level results in incorrect output

The output is only incorrect because the logic is flawed.

Step over the list yourself. It'll immediately return False at three and claim no words contain an o.

You shouldn't have a return in the loop. And you could keep track of it instead assuming you are wanting to see all the elements

```
def has_o_in_it(words):
  seen = False 
  for word in words:
    if "o" in word:
      seen = True 
  return seen
```

However, that's very verbose, and could rather be

```
return any(lambda word: 'o' in word, words)
```

Or

```
return 'o' in ''.join(words)
```